# Corrupted zip file(tried almost every tool couldn't fix)

Tags: zip

I have an around 500 Mb zip file which was deleted but i could somehow recovered it using recuva recovery tool but this zip file also show an error(invalid zip). I have tried almost every tool to recover the files from this zip but couldnt succeed so far. i am attaching the link to the corrupted zip file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iL7LDfPQOJelOseEVbY39JuthCyScXTE/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The file contains nothing but NULL bytes. Sorry, no recovery is possible.

Comment: Please update the title of your post in a way that it summarizes your question. And drop "tried almost every tool couldn't fix" part. :)

Comment: How is it possible that the size is more than 400 mb and having null bytes in it. I have some projects in this zip